# Shoelace formula in terms of squared distances

Tags: geometry, reference-request, area, polygons

The wikipedia page for polygon specifies a [shoelace formula for the signed area of a (simple) polygon in terms of squared distances.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Simple_polygons) Namely, denote by $A$ the (simple) polygon signed area and by $Q_{i,j}$ the *squared* distance between $\left(x_{i},y_{i} \right)$ and $\left(x_{j},y_{j} \right)$, then
$$
16A^{2}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}}
$$
where $x_{0}=x_{n}$ and $y_{0}=y_{n}$.

The aforementioned wikipedia page gives [a 1949 paper written in Hungarian](https://publi.math.unideb.hu/load_doi.php?pdoi=10_5486_PMD_1949_1_1_08) as the only reference for the aforementioned formula.

Is there an English reference for the squared-distance version of the shoelace formula? How can one derive it from [the usual form of the shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula#Triangle_form,_determinant_form)? How can one augment the triangulation approach featured in the proof of the usual shoelace formula in order to prove the squared-distance version?

Starting from the usual shoelace formula:
$$
\begin{align} 16A^{2} & = 16\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}} \right)^{2} \\  & = 4\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}} \right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}} \right) \\ & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}}} \\ & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & y_{i} \\ x_{i+1} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}}} \\ & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i}x_{j}+y_{i}y_{j} & x_{i}x_{j+1}+y_{i}y_{j+1} \\ x_{i+1}x_{j}+y_{i+1}y_{j} & x_{i+1}x_{j+1}+y_{i+1}y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}}} \\ & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  -2x_{i}x_{j}-2y_{i}y_{j} & -2x_{i}x_{j+1}-2y_{i}y_{j+1} \\ -2x_{i+1}x_{j}-2y_{i+1}y_{j} & -2x_{i+1}x_{j+1}-2y_{i+1}y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} }} \\ & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j}-x_{i}^{2}-x_{j}^{2}-y_{i}^{2}-y_{j}^{2} & Q_{i,j+1}-x_{i}^{2}-x_{j+1}^{2}-y_{i}^{2}-y_{j+1}^{2} \\ Q_{i+1,j}-x_{i+1}^{2}-x_{j}^{2}-y_{i+1}^{2}-y_{j}^{2} & Q_{i+1,j+1}-x_{i+1}^{2}-x_{j+1}^{2}-y_{i+1}^{2}-y_{j+1}^{2} \\ \end{vmatrix} }} \end{align}
$$

But how to continue from there?

Answer (score 1):

> How can one derive it from the usual form of the shoelace formula?

We will show that
$$
16A^{2}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}} = 0
$$
Start from the LHS, obtain
$$
16A^{2}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}} =  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}}} \\ - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left(4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}\right)}}
$$
Now recall the definition
$$
Q_{i,j} \equiv \left(x_{i}-x_{j} \right)^{2} + \left(y_{i}-y_{j} \right)^{2}
$$
and expand the determinants in order to obtain
$$
4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} = \\ a_{i}-a_{i+1}+b_{j}-b_{j+1}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
a_{i} & \equiv \left(x_{j}^{2}+y_{j}^{2}-x_{j+1}^{2}-y_{j+1}^{2} \right) \left(x_{i}^{2}+y_{i}^{2} \right) \\ & -2\left(x_{j}^{2}+y_{j}^{2} \right)\left(x_{i}x_{j+1}+ y_{i}y_{j+1}\right) \\ & +2\left(x_{j+1}^{2}+y_{j+1}^{2} \right)\left(x_{i}x_{j}+ y_{i}y_{j}\right)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
b_{j} & \equiv  2\left(x_{i+1}^{2}+y_{i+1}^{2} \right)\left(x_{i}x_{j}+ y_{i}y_{j}\right) \\ & -2\left(x_{i}^{2}+y_{i}^{2} \right)\left(x_{i+1}x_{j}+ y_{i+1}y_{j}\right)\end{align}
$$
Next recall the convention where $x_{0}=x_{n}$ and $y_{0}=y_{n}$ in order to then reduce the telescoping sums
$$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left(4\begin{vmatrix}  x_{i} & x_{i+1} \\ y_{i} & y_{i+1} \\ \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}  x_{j} & x_{j+1} \\ y_{j} & y_{j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}  Q_{i,j} & Q_{i,j+1} \\ Q_{i+1,j} & Q_{i+1,j+1} \\ \end{vmatrix}\right)}} = \\ & \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left(a_{i}-a_{i+1}+b_{j}-b_{j+1}\right)}} = \\ & \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(a_{i}-a_{i+1}\right)}} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left(b_{j}-b_{j+1}\right)}} = \\ & \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left(a_{0}-a_{n}\right)} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(b_{0}-b_{n}\right)} = \\ & \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{0} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{0} = 0
\end{align}
$$

> How can one augment the triangulation approach featured in the proof of the usual shoelace formula in order to prove the squared-distance version?

I do not think that a more succinct argument than the one made above can be given here, but I would love to be proven wrong.